# Can someone please explain energy of electrons in Bohr's model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy, atomic-physics

Energy of and electron is $$E = \text{kinetic energy} + \text{negative of potential energy}. \tag{eq-1}$$
But energy of electron in the $n$th orbital is also $$E = -\frac{13.6}{ n^2} \tag{eq-2}$$ Which means that the energy of the electron would get less and less negative as we go to further orbitals, which means that the kinetic energy of the electron is increasing (from eq-1). However that is counter-intuitive because as the electron goes from lower orbital to higher its going from a lower potential (closer to the nucleus) to a higher potential (away from nucleus i,e. against the electric field). And thus the potential energy should increase and the total energy should be more negative.

Another thing which is mind boggling is that the velocity of electron in the $n$th orbit  is, $$v = \frac{e^2}{nh\epsilon_0}$$ which suggests that velocity decreases as we go from inner to outer orbitals, which means that kinetic energy decreases! All this does not make sense to me. I know I made a mistake somewhere so if someone can help me please explain.

At the same time my textbook says that the outer energy level electrons would have more energy so, they would need less energy to be excited. But what energy do they have? The velocity equation suggests that outer electrons have less and less kinetic energy as we go to oter orbitals and eq 2 suggest that the electron even decrease in potential energy as they go in further energy levels(which should increase)

Answer (score 1):

You write

> E = kinetic energy + negative of potential energy. (eq-1)

and then

> as the electron goes from lower orbital to higher […] the potential energy should increase and the total energy should be more negative.

Remember that the electrostatic potential energy between two charges $q_1,q_2$ separated by some distance $r$ is

$$ U = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_1 q_2}{r} $$

This potential is *not strictly positive*: it has the same sign as the product of charges $q_1\cdot q_2$.  From the definition of the force $\vec F = -\vec\nabla U$ (or, in one dimension, $\vec F = -\hat x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}U$), you should be able to convince yourself that this sign convention is required to make opposite charges attract and like charges repel.

When an electron moves from a lower to a higher orbit, the potential energy increases by becoming *less negative*.  Your equation (eq-1) is wrong. The total energy is kinetic plus potential; it’s just that the potential energy between opposite charges happens to be negative.

Comment: "A negative potential energy means that work must be done against the electric field in moving the charges apart!" I quote is from a website. And this fits perfectly with the example of atom, work is being done to keep the electron against the electric field and collapsing into the nucleus, so our potential energy is negative but as we move to a further orbital more work is done to  keep the electron against the electric field of the nucleus, so it should be more negative.

Comment: https://youtu.be/qveyVsOahI8  This is for gravitational potential but it applies to charges too i guess

Comment: For the gravitational potential, the negative sign is explicit, because all masses have the same sign.

Comment: So if work is done against the field the potential energy is positive and when its done in the direction of field its negative? (for electric fields)

Comment: No, the CHANGE in PE is negative when the work of the field is positive and the CHANGE  is positive when the work of the field is negative. The actual sign of the PE depends on the reference and is completely arbitrary, in general. For the electrostatic PE with two charges of opposite signs and reference at infinite distance, the PE is negative everywhere and it increases as you increase the distance. It does not change sign at all.

Comment: The work done by a force is $W=\int \vec F\cdot \mathrm d\vec x$. If you are careful with signs and caveats about conservative forces, this is equivalent to the relationship between force and potential energy given in the answer. What matters is the sign of the *change* in the potential energy. You can change the sign of the energy itself by adding a constant offset. For instance, near Earth’s surface we may choose the gravitational “zero” to be the floor or the tabletop instead of $r\to\infty$ from Earth’s center.

Comment: @nasu suppose we take electron and nucleus as example. Do you mean that the change in potential energy is negative when the electron moves in the direction of nucleus (towards the field) and the change is positive when the electron move away from the nucleus (against the field) ? And lets also take like charges, the PE is positive when the charge moves towards the charge (against the field) and PE is negative when it moves away from the charge (towards the field), right?

Comment: Yes, the PE decrease when the charges get closer and increases when they get further away. You can get more KE if you release one charge when at a larger distance from the other one. The maximum energy is at infinite distance and this maximum is zero.

Comment: @nasu And lets also take like charges, the PE is positive when the charge moves towards the charge (against the field) and PE is negative when it moves away from the charge (towards the field), right?

Comment: @nasu and does the sign convention remain same for like negative charges too? ( against the field is positive and towards the field is negative)

Comment: No, the sign of the PE does not change as you do work, and thi sis true for the case of same sign charges too. In this case is always positive. Only the CHANGE in PE can be positive or negative, depending on how the distance changes. "Same sign" means both positive or both negative.

Comment: @nasu why doesnt energy itself have a sign and only the difference? And the distance is always measured from infinity right?

Comment: The energy does have a sign.  Who said it does not? I said that for two point charges the sign does not change when work is done on the system. And no, the distance is measured from an origin not from infinit. The energy is zero at infinite distance, but this is just the most common choice. With other choice the energy may have different signs but the differences when the distance changes will stay the same.